# QTCPSocket waitForBytesWritten и waitForReadyRead

Tags: qt, qtcpsocket

Судя по документации, не могу понять, как правильно делать передачу между сервером и клиентом. 
Если задержек нету ( т.е. клиент и сервер стоят на 127.0.0.1 ) , то подходит следующее

Сервер:

```
socket->write(Data);
```

Клиент:

```
Data = socket->readAll();
```

Передача проходит нормально. Все данные передаются полностью.

А вот что делать, когда между сервером и клиентом задержка, а данные не помещаются в один пакет? Приходится использовать задержки:
Для клиента:

```
socket-> waitForReadyRead (); // стандартно 30 сек
Data = socket->readAll();
```

Но в таком случае у меня клиент тормознёт на 30 сек. А мне это не надо. 
Пробовал разные вариации типа:

```
Data.clear();
while(!socket-> waitForReadyRead ()) // стандартно 30 сек
    Data = socket->readAll();
```

ну и т.п.

Результата не дали. 
Кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой?  Как правильно написать блокировку, чтобы дождаться полностью всех данных с сервера и при этом потерять как можно меньше времени?

Comment: У меня привязан слот моего объекта к сигналу сокета readyRead. В слоте добавляю все имеющееся в сокете в свой внутренний буфер и проверяю размер имеющихся в буфере данных. Если собрал полный пакет - обрабатываю и удаляю из буфера. Если нет - выхожу из слота и жду следующего сигнала.

Comment: Довольно радикальный способ))
Хотя, я тоже об этом задумывался.... не очень хочется переделывать

Comment: Ну, на мой вкус получилось проще копить в своем буфере ,чем в сокете. Хотя и в нем можно. Но чтобы не ждать, пока накопиться (мне так кажется) использование системы сигнал-слот очень удобно.

Comment: Ну, когда попробую сделать так-же, если ничего к вечеру не придумаю

Comment: Если придумаете другой вариант - напишите, пожалуйста, сюда. Мне было бы интересно посмотреть, поскольку сам с этой темой не очень знаком.